# SFTP Works with bash but not nologin

Tags: linux, ssh, centos, sftp

All of my sftp accounts had a default shell of /bin/nologin

All of a sudden they are failing with exit code 1.  I can change the default shell to /bin/bash and it works fine, but not a good solution.

Any ideas on what I am missing?

Thanks!

Jim

Comment: _All of a sudden_ -- what specifically changed?

Comment: only change we could notice is install of snmp packages...which should not change anything

Comment: Does `/bin/nologin` exist? Does it have the right permissions? Should it be `/sbin/nologin` instead?

Comment: @mhawke: good find, my system has it on `/usr/sbin/nologin` (which seems like an odd place to put it).

Comment: my bad it is /sbin/nologin, typo on my part.  Here are permissions:  -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 7560 Mar  3  2008 /sbin/nologin

Comment: @BigPoppa: I suggest [edit] ing the post to get the contents in legibly...

Comment: Things to check: if you're using `pam_shells` to check shells in `/etc/shells` for valid login-shells in the `/etc/pam.d/sshd` file or `/etc/pam.d/common-*` files that are included in the `sshd` PAM configuration file. Check for SELinux policy denying the execution. Check the logs for more specific error messages.

Answer (score 2):

Is there anything in the *~.bashrc* of the user you're trying to SFTP with?

This is a common gotcha, as any echo statements break SFTP / rsync, SCP